# Using Nodejs 10 HTTP2 and express crashes

Tags: node.js, https, openssl, spdy

Installed Nodejs 10.4.0 on Windows 10 64bits. I want to switch the `spdy` module with the flashing new `http2` provided by this Nodejs version.
Here is the server (commented you find the previous `spdy` solution that works):

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

/* Initialize application */
const app = express();
app.get("/api", function(req, res) {res.send("All OK\n");});

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./server.crt")
};

// require("spdy")
//  .createServer(options, app)
//  .listen(9999, (error) => {
//      if(error) {
//          console.error(error);
//          throw error;
//      }
//      else {
//          console.log(`\nServer started (HTTP/2)\n`);
//      }
//  });

require("http2")
    .createSecureServer(options, app)
    .listen(9999, (error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        }
        else {
            console.log(`\nServer started (HTTP/2)\n`);
        }
    });
```

But when I run it and connect using `curl -k https://localhost:9999/api` the server crashes with the following stack:

```
_http_incoming.js:95
  if (this.socket.readable)
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readable' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage._read (_http_incoming.js:95:19)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:449:10)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:888:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

and curl (version 7.60.0) answers: `curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0`

Isn't, as advertised somewhere, `http2` a drop-in replacement for `spdy` HTTP/2 part? Thanks!

Comment: Seems it is a well known problem with express. So, besides cooperation between node and express teams, we can only wait